# Form with textbox that opens second form

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

This is a second question connected with the C# code from this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wje_qSW9xZ8

What I want is to tie form with textbox, which saves the text in the textbox in a string and then opens second form. And when you click stop recording, this should close the second form and return to the window with the text.

I have created a second form. Made key binding, so Enter should open the second form.

I have some idea how to open the second form. The question is...

How to tie the first form with a string, used in function in the second form?
How to make the first form to open the second one? When I write the name of the variable or function in the first form, I does not recognize the variable /
function. How should I tie the two forms?

I have an idea how to do it in Windows Forms, but this one uses WPF.
In the first form, I used

```
<Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding changer}" Key="Enter"></KeyBinding>
    </Window.InputBindings>
```

But no matter where I put the code for it, it cant recognize the binding to the function.
I have tried something like this... But seems I do something wrong.

```
private void changer(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
    Form2 settingsForm = new Form2();

    // Show the settings form
    settingsForm.Show();
}
```

For the code that should return the value of the textbox, it's something like this

```
 public string name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { Set(ref _name, value); }
        }
```

If they are in the same namespace, shouldn't the binding from the first window recognize the code for the name in the second?

Comment: Your `KeyBinding` uses a binding expression. Binding like this works off of the `DataContext` of the window and that object must contain a `changer` property of type `ICommand`. You could do this using a `RelayCommand` to route the key press to the `changer` method, but this seems like overkill for where you are right now. Why not simply use code-behind in this scenario? Add a `KeyDown` event handler to your first window, and have that handler run the `changer` logic. It's good to try and think in binding/MVVM terms with WPF, but that doesn't eliminate code-behind usage.

Comment: I cant use System.Windows.Forms, because it breaks the rest of the code.

Comment: You don't need to use Forms. WPF has its own set of key events. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.keydown?view=net-5.0

Comment: Does opening second form from the first form trigger on load event? I made the 2 forms, pass the contents of the box to a second form, but the problem is that the on load event, which I coded to be collection of the video devices is not working.

Comment: It should trigger the `Loaded` event of the second window after calling the `Show` method. If you're having trouble, update your question with your the code you're trying.